# SQL syntax error when trying to alter column dimension?

Tags: sql, hana

I'm a complete SQL newbie. I want to modify the dimension of columns on a table stored in the cloud. Table 'T_PERSONS' has only 3 simple columns, 'ID', 'FIRSTNAME' and 'LASTNAME' all set to size 1 by default (for some reason). Database system is Hana MDC I believe.

My code:

```
ALTER TABLE T_PERSONS
ALTER COLUMN FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(255);
```

I get:

```
(SQL Editor) Could not execute 'ALTER TABLE T_PERSONS ALTER COLUMN FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(255)'
Error: (dberror) 257 - sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "COLUMN": line 2 col 6 (at pos 29)
```

Edit: Also, the table is empty.

Comment: Seems like SAP Hana uses another syntax, check: https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3899146

Comment: Thanks. Guess I should have googled specifically for Hana.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like SAP Hana uses another syntax.

```
alter table XXX.YYYYYYYYY alter ("DESC" NVARCHAR(500));
```

Credit to leosf6308.